# Vite/Nuxt3 not working and there are no errors

Tags: nuxt.js, localhost, vuejs3, vite

My iMac is running macOS Catalina with node v16.17.1. When I try to scaffold a Nuxt3 application using the following commands:

```
npx nuxi init mynuxt
cd mynuxt
npm install
npm run dev
```

I get an output like this:

```
Nuxi 3.0.0 15:04:45
Nuxt 3.0.0 with Nitro 1.0.0 15:04:45

> Local: http://localhost:3000/
> Network: http://192.168.1.104:3000/

✔ Nitro built in 3519 ms 15:04:59
ℹ Vite client warmed up in 6771ms 15:04:59
```

However, when I try to access http://localhost:3000/ in Firefox, it just keeps loading and nothing gets rendered. Occasionally, after many reloads (by resaving the nuxt.config.ts file) and browser refreshes, I can get the Nuxt welcome page to appear, but Hot Module Replacement (HMR) does not seem to work and the page does not update when I make changes to a file.

I'm completely confused because Vite works perfectly fine without Nuxt and I can scaffold a Vue application with Vite using the `npm create vite@latest` command and everything works.

Comment: So even without any changes to the files, it doesn't load? Do you have anything else running on port 3000?

Comment: It doesn't load without any changes to the files, and only occasionally loads after I resave the config many times, which restarts the server. Additionally, I don't see any output in the console when I make changes to a file (besides the config file which restarts the server).

I have Laravel valet running which I think is on port 80.

Comment: [Prerequisites](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/installation#prerequisites): Node.js* ([latest LTS version](https://nodejs.org/en/)) aka `v18`. Start there. Also, what did you add to your project? Got a public repo with it? Any errors in the console? Try to use a private window in Chrome for debugging purposes.

Comment: I updated Node to the latest TLS version (v18), and it seems to be working! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP updated towards Node v18 and it's now working properly.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75711628/nuxt3-application-not-working-with-blank-screen-and-no-errors.