# Nuxt3 Application Not Working with Blank Screen and No Errors

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, localhost, vite

I'm encountering issues with Nuxt3 on my iMac running macOS Catalina with node v18.15.0. While Vue/Vite and Laravel/Vite work smoothly, Nuxt3 installed via the "npx nuxi init" command behaves very abnormally without any error.

Most of the time, when I try to access the application in Firefox, I get a blank loading screen with no errors in node. Occasionally, after many refreshes and restarting Nuxt, the application starts working, but a simple change can break it again, leading to the same blank screen.

I have tried various solutions, such as disabling server-side rendering, clearing browser cache, and updating Node, but none of them have resolved the issue. The problem still persists, and I'm unsure of what else to try.

I also asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785406/vite-nuxt3-not-working-and-there-are-no-errors) about three months ago, and updating my node version seemed to alleviate the problem at the time. However, upon further use, the issue persisted and updating the node only made it less apparent. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see in your previous question that you used Nuxt 3.0.0. Did you tried to update Nuxt to the latest version (currently this is 3.2.3)?

Comment: @qiqqq I use "npx nuxi init" which automatically installs the latest version (Nuxt 3.2.3).

Comment: Not sure. But i think you have to re-install the node --lts version.

Comment: @WaleedTariq I did but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? facing the same issue

Comment: @Irakli_S
No, I still have the same problem. Dockerizing Nuxt was the only workaround I came up with. However, I still like to use Nuxt without docker as docker desktop has its own problems on my system.

Comment: @flower7182 Actually, I ended up figuring it out - in my case it was an api call timing out that was preventing the render, I had an async beforeMount function that was waiting forever.